# Unit Testing .Net CORE 2.0 WebAPI - Mock (MOQ) HTTP POST with text stream body (not model)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to unit test my HTTP POST method of my .Net CORE 2.0 API Controller which stream-reads data... Cannot use a "model" type approach as the incoming stream raw data.

Here is the basics of the controller method.

```
[HttpPost()]
[Authorize(Roles = "contributor")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitReport()
{
    IActionResult result = null;
    _logger.LogInformation("POST Request");

    var buffer = new byte[this.Request.ContentLength.Value];

    await this.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

    // Do something with the 'content'

    return (Accepted());  // Assuming all was OK
}
```

And here's my Unit Test... or rather as far as I can get..

```
[TestMethod]
public void eFormController_SubmitReport_MockService_ExpectHttpStatusAccepted()
{
    var mockContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    mockContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(context);

    var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<object>>();
    var ctrl = new Controllers.eFormsController();

    var result = ctrl.SubmitReport();

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AcceptedResult));
}
```

When I run the test as it stands, the `this.Request` property is `null` so how do I Mock a proper HTTP POST request.

Google has yet to yield any favourable results as they all assume a fully defined model, and not a **text stream**

Comment: I haven't used it, but [Flurl](https://flurl.io/docs/testable-http/) might have what you need

Comment: You have already done most of the work by using the `DefaultHttpContext`. Mock a request that has a body (stream) and give that to the context. Should be able to exercise the test from there

Comment: @Nkosi - That's where I am having trouble,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have already done most of the work by using the `DefaultHttpContext`.

Arrange a request that has a body (stream) and the necessary properties to allow the method under test to flow as expected.

Should be able to exercise the test from there

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task eFormController_SubmitReport_MockService_ExpectHttpStatusAccepted() {
    //Arrange
    var data = "Hello World!!";
    var stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    httpContext.Request.Body = stream;
    httpContext.Request.ContentLength = stream.Length;

    var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<object>>();

    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
        HttpContext = httpContext,
    };

    var controller = new Controllers.eFormsController(mockLogger.Object) {
         ControllerContext = controllerContext,
    };

    //Act
    var result = await controller.SubmitReport();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AcceptedResult));
}
```

Comment: `DefaultHttpContext` does not have a `request` property ... errr ... or does it....

Comment: @ChrisHammond https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L114

Comment: All looking good thanks .. nearly there ... Had to extract the encoding into a `byte[]` variable as need to `contentlength` ... however, controller not now reading the text (`readasync` setting buffer to `null` ... just working that now ... thanks @nkosi ..

Comment: @ChrisHammond length can be gotten from the stream.

Comment: OK... what is happening now is that in the controller, the `var buffer = ....ContentLength.Value` is resulting in a `null` when testing - ContentLegth value is correct for string passed, but buffer not initialising  to `byte[,,,]` - when running normally, buffer works.. even if initialised to fixed value